# Is there a way around for SSIS data migration

Tags: ssis

Im totally unfamiliar with SSIS migration. So I appreciate the help.

I am doing the derivation for one column from source to destination. 
the problem is:

Existing column: nVarchar(30)
Destination column: nVarchar(12)

How do I migrate the data or is there a way to write expression on derived column?

Also I m doing the same thing for another column: 
Derive from Feature, if not NULL then set to TRUE

How do I write expression on derived column?

Thanks

Comment: What if the data exceeds 12 characters, what should happen?

Answer (score 3):

To change data type from nvarchar(30) to nvarchar(12) you can use "Data conversion" component.
[image: Data conversion]

To replace NULL's with other values you can use "Derived column" with expression like this:

> ISNULL(YourColumn) ? TRUE : YourColumn

Here is an example for nvarchar column:

[image: Derived column]